# Uploading a large file with PHP/JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to enable uploads of up to around 12MB for a site, unfortunately using a basic form element like:

```
<input type='file' name='videofile' />
```

doesn't really seem to cut it, it seems to timeout after a certain period (I've tried upping the server variables, not sure if this is a browser thing).

Are there any readily available HTML5/JavaScript solutions that I can use here? I've tried Googling around but it seems there isn't much information around ... a few people have proposed Flash/Java applets, but that's something I really don't want to get into.

Comment: it's prolly the php settings:"memory_limit=100M","post_max_size=100M","upload_max_filesize=100M"

Comment: Seems like a PHP problem - take a look at this article. http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 directives you should alter in order to increase the allowed upload file size, these are: `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`, so one would just post the below snippet of code in  the php init script (index.php etc) in order to increase the allowed upload file size.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M'); // this is optional.
ini_set('post_max_size','64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','64M');
```

L.E: If you are handling real big files, then you should consider chunking: [Upload 1GB files using chunking in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447837/upload-1gb-files-using-chunking-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) makes both an HTML5 and a flash version, you just download the one you want.

Also, be mindful of changing ini settings with PHP as some servers will allow this, others won't, and others will up to a certain size. You will want to check your php settings to see if this is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is a browser problem. Setting the values in your .htaccess or php.ini should work:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 15M
php_value post_max_size 15M
```

Alternatively you could use [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with maximum execution time of PHP script (by default 30 seconds). You can change it with function set_time_limit, but it does not work in safe mode.