# Upload large HD Video files in PHP

Tags: php, http, file-upload

Am working on you tube like project, have a requirement to upload large video files size above 1GB. Normally i did simple uploads only using HTTP POST. There i can adjust these options in php.ini file to upload large files

```
php_value upload_max_filesize
php_value post_max_size
php_value max_input_time
php_value max_execution_time
```

But am not sure about this case. Can i upload this much file size using HTTP?

What would be the best solution? Is there a way to do upload large files strictly through PHP and HTML? If not, what is the best solution to upload large files while still being able to pass the filename to a database? Your help is much appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: this has been discussed here on SO many times, search for chunked uploads and you'll get the solution.

Comment: Thanks i will work on that way ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Twisted1919, @Stony for guiding me in right direction. I got the answer from following link

[Upload 1GB files using chunking in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447837/upload-1gb-files-using-chunking-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

set php.ini from your xampp
edit on this :- 
php_value upload_max_filesize

php_value post_max_size

php_value max_input_time

php_value max_execution_time