# Decompress a file which is splited into chunks in the server

Tags: php, ftp, server, compression

I have made a php script that compresses and splits a file into chunks of 63MB (for the restriction of `max_upload_size` variable) and uploads them into the server.

Is there a way to decompress it and join the parts so that there is only one file in the server? I think that the variable `max_upload_size` do not affect the download so that people will be able to download big files. Could you confirm it?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447837/upload-1gb-files-using-chunking-in-php

Comment: Great, I think it is really what I need. But actually it is not a duplicate; while the other post need to split a file before uploading, I need to join it together after uploading. Anyway, thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Chunking is both. You have to split a file into multiple parts to not hit  `max_upload_size` and then merge them all together on the server.