# Big file upload to website

Tags: php, file, upload, system

I would like to make a site like YouTube where people can upload videos. First I wanted to create a php upload system, but this couldn't handle the size of the videos.

Does anyone have a way to upload large documents or videos?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can find the solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102809/how-to-upload-large-files-above-500mb-in-php

Comment: A better method would be to upload *chunks*, you then don't need to fiddle with the server settings, can add progress bars etc and do not open yourself up for an upload attack - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447837/upload-1gb-files-using-chunking-in-php